# Class 'Httpful\Bootstrap' not found

Tags: rest, centos, directadmin, httpful

I'm working on CentOS 6.0 64-Bit with DirectAdmin 1.53.2 with PHP 7.0. Everything is OK but recenlty I have error

```
Class 'Httpful\Bootstrap' not found
```

on pages where using script from http://phphttpclient.com

```
<?php require_once('httpful.phar'); ?>
```

This error occures in PHP error logs:

```
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'phar://httpful.phar/Httpful/Bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php70/lib/php') in /home/webster/domains/webster-studio.pl/public_html/portfolio/polonus/adds/httpful.phar on line 4\n'
```

For now, I figure out that restart service php7 remove that error but only on first load page ... After reload error show again ...

```
service php-fpm70 restart
```

Maybe someone know more about that situation, what can I do to remove that error permanently ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem gone after upgrade PHP to 7.1 ...